# Verify if the sum of 2 numbers is x using DivideEtImpera

Tags: divide-and-conquer

I want to check if the sum of 2 numbers (a and b) from a given array A is x in O(nlogn). I wrote the following code but it appears it's not working properly. Why is that?

```
bool flag = false;

int pairDivideEtImpera(int A[], int left, int right, int x) {
    if (left == right)
        return A[left];

    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    if (pairDivideEtImpera(A, left, mid, x) + pairDivideEtImpera(A, mid + 1, right, x) == x)
        flag = true;
}
```

I take every 2 elements from the array and I verify if the sum is x. If so, the flag will be true and I'll know I have a pair (a,b), where a+b = x. What am I missing and why this doesn't show the right thing?

Comment: What do you return when left is not equal to right?

Comment: Why should I return something?

Comment: Functions always have to return something. Otherwise, what do you expect `pairDivideEtImpera(A, left, mid, x)` to be when `left` is not equal to `mid`? Right now it will most likely be some uninitialized random rubbish.

Comment: So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing you can use divide-and-conquer in this case. Here is a solution in O(nlogn)

STEP 1: You sort the array, it takes you O(nlogn) operations.

STEP 2: You look at the smallest and biggest value. If the sum is too big you decrease the big value, if it is too small you increase the small value. Do this until you find x or big value == small calue

Here is the code for step 2 (with a sorted array A)

```
int left =0;
int right=A.length - 1;
bool flag = false;
while (right>left){
    int y = A[left]+A[right]
    if (y==x){
        flag = true;
        break;
    } else if (y>x) {
        right--;
    } else {
        left++;
    }
}
```